# Are there safe places to store luggage for a couple days in New Delhi?

Tags: luggage-storage, new-delhi

I'm travelling India for a few weeks.  We plan on doing a few overnight trips from New Delhi and do not want to carry all our luggage with us.  We don't have anything really valuable but it would be very inconvenient if all our clothes went missing.

Comment: Though you might not be in this situation, note that any luxury hotel provides this service.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If you'll be traveling on train from New Delhi, then you can use the **cloak rooms** and **safety lockers** available at **New Delhi railway station**.

> Most major stations have cloak rooms and lockers where you can leave
>   your luggage, on payment of prescribed charges. This passenger amenity
>   ensures safe custody of your luggage, giving you the freedom to spend
>   a day or two as you desire. The process of depositing your luggage in
>   the cloak room has been simplified for your convenience. All you have
>   to do is to deposit the luggage duly locked, where upon a receipt will
>   be given to you. This receipt, duly signed as an acknowledgement of
>   having received your luggage, should be surrendered along with the
>   prescribed charges at the time of delivery. Delivery of luggage will
>   not be done without the surrender of your receipt. Pleaese ensure that
>   all baggage/hold-alls/travel bags are locked securely. Otherwise,
>   these may not be accepted by the railway personnel.

You will have to produce your train ticket, and Identity card (this is needed at many stations). There is a nominal hourly rate charge, which is calculated per piece of luggage. Your luggage must be locked.

The [current rates](http://www.indianrailways.gov.in/railwayboard/uploads/directorate/traffic_comm/Comm-cir-2k13/CC-09_2013_1.pdf) for using Cloak rooms and Storage lockers:

```
Duration                                Cloak Room          Storage Locker
For first 24 hours or part thereof      Rs 15 per package   Rs 20
For each subsequent 24 hours or
part thereof                            Rs 20 per package   Rs 30
```

Comment: How about large backpacks? Often, they cannot realistically be locked.

Comment: @MarkCarter The large backpacks can be submitted in the cloak room. Last I checked, cloak room was just a room to store the luggage (which is of course secured), and it accommodates most luggage items. Safety lockers are for smaller and more valuable items.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using the Delhi Airport Metro Express (at the New Delhi station), there is a cloakroom just outside the barriers. To get here, you cross the from the mezzanine level (between the bottom arrivals and upper departures levels), across the catwalk towards the metro, and walk past the stairs/entrance to the station.

Bag does not need to be locked. I believe it's cash only. The photos show the hourly and flat-rate prices to store luggage (visited February 2019).

[image]

[image]

Comment: +1 for convenient location, but RS 600 per day is *really* expensive by Indian standards.  For comparison, at Indian Railways stations the standard price is Rs 20/day.

Answer (score -2):

There is a service called bagdolo which offers cloakrooms all around Delhi, you can find the nearest one and drop your luggage there. They charge around Rs 80 ($1.2) per bag. They also provide safety seal to secure your luggage.

They also have service in several other major cities of India. It can be booked online through their website/app.

Comment: Are you affiliated with this service? You posted this exact same thing, word for word, last week on a different question.

Comment: This question was more relevant for my answer, so answered again here. I have provided more relevant information now.